# Problem with Indigo and Gazebo 2.2

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with Gazebo 2.2. When I launch gazebo, I see this error

```
:~$ gazebo
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.3
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.3
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.1.152
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.1.152
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Error [gazebo.cc:220] Waited 11 seconds for namespaces. Giving up.
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [1,0471975511965976] for key[horizontal_fov]
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [0,100000001] for key[near]
```

How Can I solve?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199401/problem-with-indigo-and-gazebo-2.2/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment I replaced "http://gazebosim.org/models" in "http://old.gazebosim.org/models". Now it all works!

Thanks to all!!!

UPDATE

The best way to solve this problem is update Gazebo 2.2, but you must add packages.osrfoundation.org at Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then if you update Ubuntu, It install Gazebo 2.2.5.
Now it all works!

---

Originally posted by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) with karma: 402 on 2014-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-12-15**:
interesting...
***where*** did you change that link?
in which file?

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-12-15**:
In "source /usr/local/share/gazebo-2.2/setup.sh".

I think there's a problem with http://gazebosim.org/models link.

**Comment by [Laszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28564/laszlo/) on 2016-11-18**:
cool,it works,thanks a lot

**Comment by [Anurag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28030/anurag/) on 2017-04-28**:
I replaced it in /usr/share/gazebo and /usr/share/gazebo-2.2. Still the problem persists. Infact, gazebo stil uses the previous url

Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:1134

**Comment by [Safwan.Ahmad](https://answers.ros.org/users/39010/safwan.ahmad/) on 2018-12-14**:
After modifying the URL you have to source the same file:
source /usr/share/gazebo
source /usr/share/gazebo-2.2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For error

```
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [1,0471975511965976] for key[horizontal_fov]
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [0,100000001] for key[near]
```

Workaround:
`$ export LC_NUMERIC=C`
or you might want to add that line to your ~/.bashrc.

But the problem with "namespace not found", I had the same. Two days ago I installed ros indigo -> gazebo -> gazebo_ros plugin and kobuki_gazebo, everything ok. Now I reinstall them, with the bit different: first gazebo -> then ros indigo... and I encounter errors like you

Sorry for my bad English :P

**UPDATE**

Finally I got it! Gazebo try to collect models from http://gazebosim.org/models but there 's something wrong... the folder `~/.gazebo/models` does not exist and Gazebo simulator can not start. Here's a bit more simple solution: run
`$ wget -r -R "index\.html*" http://old.gazebosim.org/models/`

to get all models from gazebosim and copy them into `~/.gazebo/models` folder (after you `mkdir models` inside `~/.gazebo`) and everything will be ok.

**UPDATE 2**

See @Juni [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/199401/problem-with-indigo-and-gazebo-22#post-id-212237) for better way to download models.

---

Originally posted by [sontdhust](https://answers.ros.org/users/21110/sontdhust/) with karma: 201 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juni](https://answers.ros.org/users/8961/juni/) on 2015-06-26**:
This solution worked for me. But I had to replace the link `http://old.gazebosim.org/models/` with `http://models.gazebosim.org/`. And a better and faster way is to download the models files from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/downloads).

**Comment by [sontdhust](https://answers.ros.org/users/21110/sontdhust/) on 2015-06-26**:
Oh my God... I spent half an hour downloading dozens of these models by wget >_<... thank u so muchhhh...

**Comment by [ljxiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26431/ljxiang/) on 2016-04-06**:
Thanks for your method.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-02-02**:
The step mentioned by Juni about downloading the file and unzipping it in the ~/.gazebo/models/ folder worked for me. I tried to edit the setup.sh file but couldn't find it in the specified folder. Thank you

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2017-03-05**:
This helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo I have the same problem.
Unfortunately, none of your solutions work for me.

Here the snippet from the terminal

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.5
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[1;Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.5
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

32mMsg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.2.15
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.2.15
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Error [gazebo.cc:220] Waited 11 seconds for namespaces. Giving up.
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [1,0471975511965976] for key[horizontal_fov]
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [0,100000001] for key[near]
```

And the content of the setup.sh

```
export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
export GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-2.2:/usr/share/gazebo_models
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gazebo-2.2/plugins
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gazebo-2.2/plugins
export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0
```

Then for me everything looks fine, but it does't  work.

Perhaps any of you has a idea to solve my problem.

Is it a problem with ubuntu 14.04.2 or with virtual box?

I am surprised that this problem has not occurred more often.

---

Originally posted by [Mondi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22211/mondi/) with karma: 51 on 2015-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2015-08-10**:
I've had the same problem. Through this [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros) you can find more information about installing related packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay I have a workaround similar to one devised earlier:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gazebo-2.2/setup.sh
```

well it would look something like this:

```
export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
export GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-2.2:/usr/share/gazebo_models
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gazebo-2.2/plugins
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gazebo-2.2/plugins
export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0
```

you must change the "GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI" to http://models.gazebosim.org
and that's it.

I think what it does is it starts looking for namespaces on the website that you mentioned in setup.sh and then, if matched, it fetches the required models.

---

Originally posted by [mohit_rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/28477/mohit_rai/) with karma: 21 on 2016-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same problem I faced after the fresh installation of indigo.
So, in home folder, press ctrl+h to see the hidden files.
Then find the .gazebo file and copy the gazebo "models" file from the internet.
And it worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [mkorkmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26386/mkorkmaz/) with karma: 31 on 2017-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo needs to find models, the download link in 2.2 is no longer valid, so it can't download and find the models.
You can manually download the models from https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/downloads/, extract it in ~/.gazebo/models/

---

Originally posted by [plutotx](https://answers.ros.org/users/39244/plutotx/) with karma: 11 on 2018-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1